# How similar is C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between C++ and C#/.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291513/differences-between-c-and-c-net)

I am reading [this C# tutorial](http://ssw.jku.at/Teaching/Lectures/CSharp/Tutorial/Part1.pdf) and it says "similar to Java (75%) C++(10%)". is that true? I thought C# and C++ were the same language except for few handy abstractions which visual studio provides.

Comment: Related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291513/differences-between-c-and-c-net

Comment: A percentage suggests a way of measuring. We'll never agree on how to measure. Or do you have something in mind?

Comment: "the same language except for few handy abstractions"? You are probably confusing C# with C++/CLI...

Comment: Well, they do have a `C` in common for starters. Then there is the fact that if you overlap the two `++` you can make it look *kind of* like a `#`...

Answer (score 6):

C# and C++ are *completely* different languages. Even saying that they are 10% similar is probably an exaggeration. The main similarity between C# and C++ is that they both inherited basic syntax and the first letter of their name from C.