# Start process and get its output constantly

Tags: c#

I have a console program written in c++, and I would like to continually check its output to use in my c# project.

This is the code I've tried to steal from another StackOverflow question, but with no luck.

Edit:( By no luck, I mean: the output is pretty much empty, although if I set p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow to false, I can see my script.exe launch and output into its window. )

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"external\script.exe";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine("Output:");
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: is your *script.exe* returning something???

Comment: What do you mean "with no luck"? What is the observed behavior? What does it do? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa, It is pritning (or writing into its console)

Comment: @mason the output is pretty much empty altough if i set p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow to false, i can see my script.exe launch and output into its own window.

Comment: Does it need to be in C#? This would be a lot simpler to do in Powershell?

Comment: You're identified your code as c++. It's not. See [How similar are c# and c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6997295/2791540)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it had to do with where the output was going. The solution was to run cmd and execute my script from the cmd process. See this answer to another question for more information. [reading from stdout and stderr together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47382540/11754657) Your new code would look like:

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c yourscriptpath.exe 2>&1";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine("Output:");
    Console.WriteLine(output);
```